# Getting activity from utility classes

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I have a common problem in my application where I extract functionality into classes that handles this functionality, and nothing else. The problem is that I often need an instance of an Activity for much of this functionality, like reading files, access to the database etc etc, so I have to pass the current activity to the utility and that make the code ugly.

Now I'm looking into setting up a singleton that holds a reference to my "start"-activity and then inject this Singleton into my utillites. But, and this is the but, I don't control if an activity is removed or still active, Android does. So my Activity might not be enough alive to be usable anymore.

So, to conclude, I don't feel confident that it is safe to store the reference to an activity and I don't want to pass the current activity with every call. What is the solution. Am I paranoid? :-)

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store references to activities. You can use the application context instead: there is only one, and it is guaranteed to be available as long as your app is alive. For easier access you might want to define an `Application` class and add a `getInstance()` method to it. The problem with this approach is that not all operations that require a context can be performed using the application context. Anything related to views is likely to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that many Android operations require an `Activity` or (more usually) just a `Context`. Provided your utility classes aren't holding onto references beyond the lifecycle of the `Context`, then you should be fine.

I would shy away from a singleton referring to your 'start' Activity, since the first Activity of your app may be destroyed even if a subsequent Activity is active and visible.

An alternative approach may be to implement your own abstract class (e.g. `BaseActivity`) implementing or wrapping the functionality of your utility class that all your other Activities inherit from, rather than `Activity` directly. This way you can keep the plumbing away from the logic of your main activities.